# Creating an extendable finite state machine

Tags: c#, generics, state-machine

I would like to create a base class representing a finite state machine which will then be extended by various components. It should be as generic as possible and allow only states designed specifically for that machine to be executed. This is what I got so far:

```
public interface IState<out T> where T : FiniteStateMachine {
    void Enter( T p );
    void Execute( T p );
    void Exit( T p );
}

public class FiniteStateMachine {
    public IState<FiniteStateMachine> CurrentState { get; private set; }

    public void ChangeState( IState<FiniteStateMachine> s ) {
        if ( CurrentState != null )
            CurrentState.Exit( this );

        CurrentState = s;
        s.Enter( this );
    }
}

public class Car : FiniteStateMachine { }
public class Boat : FiniteStateMachine { }

public class CarState : IState<Car> {
    public void Entra( Car f ) { }
    public void Esegui( Car f ) { }
    public void Esci( Car f ) { }
}

public class BoatState : IState<Boat> {
    public void Enter( Boat f ) { }
    public void Execute( Boat f ) { }
    public void Exit( Boat f ) { }
}
```

And here's a little sample:

```
var car = new Car( );
var boat = new Boat( );

// These are fine
car.ChangeState( new CarState( ) );
boat.ChangeState( new BoatState( ) );

// These aren't
car.ChangeState( new BoatState( ) );
boat.ChangeState( new CarState( ) );
```

Basically, I want `Car.ChangeState` to accept only states which implement `IState<Car>`, `Boat.ChangeState` to accept only `IState<Boat>` and so on.

I am not able to achieve such behavior though, can somebody help me?

Comment: A list of your wants is not a question. What's your question?

Comment: @EricLippert Basically how to make things work as I have described

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Basically, I want Car.ChangeState to accept only states which implement `IState<Car>`, `Boat.ChangeState` to accept only `IState<Boat>` and so on.

The typical way to do this is to use a variation on the Curiously Recurring Template pattern. I describe the C# version of the pattern here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx

I recommend that you *not* pursue this. This pattern makes your code hard to understand and the restriction that it *actually* makes is not the restriction you want. The type system is simply not good at representing the kind of constraint that you want. The type system cannot be all things to all people.

Comment: I see your point, and I'll follow your advice. My purpose was to avoid inserting a cast at the beginning of every IState method, but it really isn't worth it. Thank you :)